# Python Tkinter Canvas Draw Semicircle

Tags: python, tkinter

It'd seem so obvious at first that I never thought of how I would do this - how can I draw a semicircle?
I've tried using an chord:

```
canvas.create_arc(x1, y1, x2, y2, style="chord",...)
```

But no combination of coordinates I can think of work. So I tried using an arc:

```
canvas.create_arc(x1, y1, x2, y2, style="arc",...)
```

Which also doesn't work - and pieslice doesn't either.

In summary, how can I make a semicircle using  tkinter? (as in like canvas.create...)

Comment: You need more than just the bounding box coordinates to draw an arc: you also need the `start=` and `extent=` options.  `extent=180` should make a semicircle, adjust `start` to orient how you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a semicircle with an arc. In addition to the coordinates you need to give a `start` and `extent`.

**extent**=*degrees*

Specifies the size of the angular range occupied by the arc. The arc's range extends for degrees degrees counter-clockwise from the starting angle given by the **start** option. *Degrees* may be negative. If it is greater than 360 or less than -360, then degrees modulo 360 is used as the extent.

**start**=*degrees*

Specifies the beginning of the angular range occupied by the arc. *Degrees* is given in units of degrees measured counter-clockwise from the 3-o'clock position; it may be either positive or negative.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=200)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.create_arc(100, 100, 200, 200, start=20, extent=180, fill="red")

root.mainloop()
```

[image]