# How can I draw random semi circle, same size but different orientations in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I would like to plot different semicircles same radius but different orientation different places. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the patch collection in matplotlib.

[The Wedge object](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Wedge.html) plots a circle wedge at `center = (x,y)` of radius `r` and you give it the start (`theta1`) and end (`theta2`) angles. If you want a semicircle, then `theta2 = theta1 + 180`, and `theta1` would be how much you rotate the "canonical" semicircle (the one that goes from 0 to 180 degrees). To declare the objects:

```
wedges = []
for row in semicircle_specs:
    wedge = Wedge((row['x'], row['y']), RADIUS, row['angle'], row['angle'] + 180)
    wedges.append(wedge)
```

If you don't wish to work with matplotlib, [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640201/python-tkinter-canvas-draw-semicircle) provides a solution with Tkinter

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but is it hollow semicircle?

Comment: in matplotlib can set the fill to false, the transparency with alpha, and the edgecolor to whatever you prefer. I recommend you play with the kwargs see if you get a setting that you like: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Wedge.html#matplotlib.patches.Wedge